# Send Unix commands to PuTTY

Tags: vba, putty

I have opened and logged into a PuTTY session. Now I am trying to send commands like `cd` to the same session using below code:

```
Sub open_putty()
    Dim UserName 'assign user name
    Dim Passwrd 'assign password
    Dim TaskID As Long
    UserName = "UNAME"
    Passwrd = "PWD"
    TaskID = shell("path/putty.exe " & UserName & "@SERVERNAME -pw " & Passwrd, vbMaximizedFocus)
    AppActivate TaskID, True

    SendKeys "cd somedirectory"
End Sub
```

First issue I am facing is on `AppActivate TaskID, True` line. Error message is

> Runtime error 5, invalid procedure call, or argument.

I have commented that line and now PuTTY session is opened and able to login, but then unable to send the command using `SendKeys`.

I have tried to search on this but not getting specific answer, so asking posting it here.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] as you are missing required code, for example `shell()` is not a built in function so it must be defined somewhere.

Comment: I'm not a Windows person, so I'm probably doubly baffled by the idea that you would use VB for this, but have you considered doing things over on the Unix side?  Expect and friends are very easy to find examples for.

Comment: As an aside, when I found PuTTY hard to script, I discovered its fork [Kitty](http://kitty.9bis.net/), but thankfully, I no longer need to touch Windows at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute putty commands](//stackoverflow.com/q/32049615)

Comment: Guys thanks for your reply, @Lankymart, it is the code I am currently using and sheel is not defined as you are expecting. Also I read the information you think duplicate of and tried this, I am not very sure how should I call the external file (file in which the unix commands are saved).

Comment: @SuhasDhokle I'm not sure what any of that means. All I said was the line `TaskID = shell("path/putty.exe " & UserName & "@SERVERNAME -pw " & Passwrd, vbMaximizedFocus)` is calling a function called `shell()`. I'm fairly sure there is no in-built function in VBScript called `shell()` which means it is user defined and for this code to be reproducible the definition for `shell()` would need including.

Comment: Ok. but can you help me achieving the purpose please? I am able to login to unix / putty but wanted to pass few more unix commands as well, which I am unable to do.

Comment: @SuhasDhokle again, how can I help if I can't run the code for myself because it doesn't include all the needed code? I run this it will give an error `shell is not defined` or similar.

Comment: Sub open_putty()
    Dim UserName 'assign user name
    Dim Passwrd 'assign password
    Dim TaskID As Long
   Dim Shell
  Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    UserName = "UNAME"
    Passwrd = "PWD"
    TaskID = shell("path/putty.exe " & UserName & "@SERVERNAME -pw " & Passwrd, vbMaximizedFocus)
    AppActivate TaskID, True

    SendKeys "cd somedirectory"
End Sub

Comment: Hope this code will help you

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript. Is this VBA (the macro language of the MS Office programs)? Besides, if you want to run commands on a remote Unix host you may want to look into `plink`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers good catch missed the `As Long` bit in the code, definitely not VBScript. That I'll explain the [`Shell()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437.aspx) as well.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, yes it is a VBA. Also I am on a client network and can not use 'plink'. So I am trying to use VBA for this.

Comment: If you can use PuTTY, why should you not be able to use `plink`? It's from the same suite, and it's a standalone executable that you can just put whereever you want.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, If I have to use plink, how the code will look like? Is it same as below?
`Sub open_putty()
    Dim UserName 'assign user name
    Dim Passwrd 'assign password
    Dim TaskID As Long
    UserName = "UNAME"
    Passwrd = "PWD"
    TaskID = shell("path/plink.exe " & UserName & "@SERVERNAME -pw " & Passwrd, vbMaximizedFocus)
    AppActivate TaskID, True

    SendKeys "cd somedirectory"
End Sub`

Comment: No. Please read the [documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). For running multiple commands you may want to write them to a temporary file and redirect that into the command: `Shell("cmd /c plink ... < tempfile")`.